# Dynamic return type that depends on subclass in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract

I would like to declare a base class `Command` with abstract getter `GetValue`. Then I subclass this to `TalkCommand` and `SpendCommand` for example.

Both class must implement `GetValue`, however, I want to `TalkCommand` to return `string` type for `GetValue` (what to talk?) and I want the `SpendCommand` to return `int` type. (how much to spend?)

I don't know how to write this in the `Command` base class. Is this design possible in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In addition to Manfred's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37526498/411632) I want to give you a hint to go further.

While generics provide you a valuable tool to define `GetValue` return type, you wouln't be able to perform the following upcast:

```
abstract class Command<T>
{
    public abstract T GetValue();
}

class TalkCommand : Command<string>
{
    public override string GetValue()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}

// TalkCommand isn't Command<object>
Command<object> cmd = new TalkCommand();
```

Instead of defining your command as an abstract class, I would start defining it as an interface with [*covariance*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx):

```
public interface ICommand<out T>
{
    T GetValue();
}
```

And the whole abstract class could implement `ICommand<out T>`:

```
abstract class Command<T> : ICommand<T>
{
    public abstract T GetValue();
}
```

Now you can upcast an implementation of `ICommand<string>` to `ICommand<object>`:

```
ICommand<string> cmd = new TalkCommand();
ICommand<object> cmd2 = cmd;
```

This is good, because you get the best of two worlds:

- Your commands have strong return types.
- Your commands can be generically treated as implementations of `ICommand<object>` and this let you call `GetValue` and return `object` in some situations where you don't know the generic argument to provide or you don't need it at all.

Answer (score 2):

If return type must be different depending on subclass, you would be better off not having this method in the base class.

The idea behind having a base type in the first place is to let you deal with all subclasses in a uniform way. One should be able to write

```
Command cmd = ... // One of subclasses
<some-type> val = cmd.GetValue();
```

and replace `<some-type>` with the actual type. In your case, however, there is no common base type other than `object` for `int` and `string`, so having a different return type becomes pointless.

You can implement `GetValue` as generic, like this:

```
abstract class Command {
    abstract T GetValue<T>();
    ...
}
```

but that would require the caller to pass the desired type as type parameter of `GetValue`, which would defeat the purpose of having `GetValue` in the base class.

**Possible fix:** One approach that lets callers stay away from knowing the type is visitor - make an interface that lets `Command` "push" the value into the caller, like this:

```
IValueGetter {
    void SetInt(int v);
    void SetString(string v);
}

abstract class Command {
    abstract void GetValue(IValueGetter g);
}
class TalkCommand {
    override void GetValue(IValueGetter g) {
        g.SetString("hello");
    }
}
class BuyCommand {
    override void GetValue(IValueGetter g) {
        g.SetInt(123);
    }
}
```

Now the caller can interact with `Command` without knowing the type of its `GetValue`. Commands that produce an `int` would call back `SetInt`, while commands that produce `string` would call `SetString`.

Comment: Wouldn't be this approach valid before generics hit .NET? :\

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer The "possible fix" approach is definitely valid.

Comment: Uhm well, at the end of the day, there're many valid solutions to the same problem. BTW, I believe that your approach have some issues. For example, whenever you need to set a new type of value you need to extend the interface and implement the whole new `SetXXX` methods. Isn't this solved easily with generics after all?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer My point is that generic approach creates more problems than it solves, because subclasses of the same type become non-interchangeable in situations when return types differ.

Comment: Unless you define an interface with covariance as I've described in my answer, am I wrong? You can still retain the pros of working with a strongly-typed command while *who manages these commands* can treat all as `ICommand<object>`. Is this the problem you're talking about?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Which is exactly why most non-generic base classes of generic classes use `object` to substitute for `T`.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Covariance is only marginally better than having base class return `object`, and providing subclass-specific methods returning the desired type. Returning an object in place of strong type borders on the famous "But I was thinking of a plan / To dye one's whiskers green / And always use so large a fan / That they could not be seen" from [Haddocks' Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes)

Comment: Off-topic: I had never opened your profile (but I already knew you because of reading your answers in other Q&As). So you're the RRoD Man :P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer No, that's not me, I just borrowed the icon :-) In case you are wondering, my nick comes from [this old joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinkenlights).

Answer (score 1):

Only if your base class `Command` is generic or you don't mind working with `object`.

**Generic Example**

If you always work with a known instance type, this would be the best approach since you can with the data type you need without casting.

```
abstract class Command<T>
{
    public abstract T GetValue();
}

class TalkCommand : Command<string>
{
    public override string GetValue()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}

class SpendCommand : Command<int>
{
    public override int GetValue()
    {
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

**Object Example**

This is a very universal approach, pretty much what WPF does with `DependencyProperties` and non-generic collections like `IList` or `IEnumerable`.

```
abstract class Command
{
    public abstract object GetValue();
}

class TalkCommand : Command
{
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}

class SpendCommand : Command
{
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

**Hybrid Example**

If you want to be able to use both, you'll need a non-generic base class and inherit another abstract generic class from it.

```
abstract class Command
{
    public abstract object GetValue();
}

abstract class Command<T> : Command
{
    public T GetTypedValue()
    {
        return (T)GetValue();
    }
}   

class TalkCommand : Command<string>
{
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return "Test";
    }
}

class SpendCommand : Command<int>
{
    public override object GetValue()
    {
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could go the opposite direction. `Command<T>` is the *main implementation* while the `Command` without generic type parameter is a derived class of `Command<T>`. That way, common uses of commands will avoid an unnecessary cast from object to `T`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I disagree. When I need to use `Command<T>` without knowing its type (`T`), I can't create a `Command<Unknown>` but because it inherits from `Command` I can use that and all functions that are defined within. It's done that way all across the .Net Framework (e.g. `IEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable`)

Comment: Well, you're right, it may depend on the project too... BTW maybe I'm mistaken, but the power of covariance/contravariance is that since generics have these capababilities, there're a lot of issues than can be solved that way instead of using class inheritance unless you think that generics are a waste of time and are too complex (I'm not talking about you, I just love generic programming!)

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Generics are a wonderful concept. Being able to reuse code without resorting to duck-typing is great. However using generics simply to reuse code for multiple data types but without the need to use any of the functionality in a non-generic context is a rather rare case for me.